# How to attach a label to a Bing Maps MapPolygon?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, bing-maps

I'm using a Silverlight Bing Maps Control, and have defined a number of MapPolygon areas as children to the map control.
What I want ideally, is the ability to add a TextBlock label to the center of the interior of the MapPolygon.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need an approximate center of the polygon, you can find the center of its bounding box and programatically add a TextBlock over the polygon.

So something like this might work:

(XAML)

```
    <MapControl:Map x:Name="MyMap">
        <MapControl:Map.Children>
            <MapControl:MapPolygon Fill="Red" Stroke="Yellow" StrokeThickness="5" Opacity="0.7">
                <MapControl:MapPolygon.Locations>
                    <m:LocationCollection>
                        <m:Location>20, -20</m:Location>
                        <m:Location>20, 20</m:Location>
                        <m:Location>-20, 20</m:Location>
                        <m:Location>-20, -20</m:Location>
                    </m:LocationCollection>
                </MapControl:MapPolygon.Locations>
            </MapControl:MapPolygon>
        </MapControl:Map.Children>
    </MapControl:Map>
```

(Codebehind)

```
     public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    private MapLayer tbLayer;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tbLayer = new MapLayer();

        List<TextBlock> newTbs = new List<TextBlock>();

        // loop through the maps children and find the polygons
        foreach (var child in MyMap.Children)
        {
            if (child is MapPolygon)
            {
                var poly = child as MapPolygon;

                // get the average lat and long to calculate the "center"-ish of the polygon
                var avgLat = poly.Locations.Select(l => l.Latitude).Average();
                var avgLon = poly.Locations.Select(l => l.Longitude).Average();

                TextBlock tb = new TextBlock
                                   {
                                           Text = "Hey there. I'm a polygon."
                                   };

                // set the position of the textblock and add it to a new map layer
                MapLayer.SetPositionOrigin(tb, PositionOrigin.Center);
                MapLayer.SetPosition(tb, new Location(avgLat, avgLon));
                tbLayer.Children.Add(tb);
            }
        }

        // add the new maplayer to the parent map
        MyMap.Children.Add(tbLayer);

    }
}
```

If your polygons are oddly shaped and not nice little squares like my generic example, then you might need to get a little dirtier. In which case, you may need a web service (WCF) that can calculate your centroid of the polygon. I don't think theres a simple way in Silverlight to do this.

It would be a process similar to the following:

1. Send the points to a WCF service method.
2. Load up a [SqlGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeometry.aspx) object with your points, probably by forming [WKT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) with those points and using SqlGeometry.Parse
3. Call STCentroid on your SqlGeometry object.
4. return SqlGeometry.STAsText to return the WKT of the point you just got by calling STCentroid.

It's a bit of a mess, but doing spatial stuff in Silverlight is always messy in my experience.

Hope that helps and wasn't too long winded :)